# Inputting certain value into exe using subprocess

Tags: python, windows, automation, subprocess, exe

I want to enter a value (Windows 10 key) into Microsoft PID Checker to check if the key is valid or not , how to do that without showing a GUI , only receiving an output with validation state ?

```
import subprocess

def check_windows_key(key):
    command = r'C:\Users\islam\Desktop\Microsoft PID Checker.exe /s {}'.format(key)
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, text=True)
        output = result.stdout.strip()
        if "Product Key is valid" in output:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Microsoft PID Checker tool not found.")
        return False

# Provide the Windows 10 key you want to check
key_to_check = "XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX"

# Call the function to check the validation of the key
is_valid = check_windows_key(key_to_check)

if is_valid:
    print("The Windows 10 key is valid.")
else:
    print("The Windows 10 key is not valid.")
```

**That what I got when I run the code only the exe run without doing anything**

[image]

**That what outputs when I'm entering a valid key**
[image]